# Replace text between a pattern

Tags: java, replace

I have to replace a text between a pattern. Here is the function:

```
public String replace(String text) {
    String text = "My name is %NAME%.";
    String pattern = "%NAME%";
    String textReplaced = "";
    "Here comes the code"
    return textReplaced;
}
```

The result of execute the function replace("Darius");
must be a String like this: "My name is Darius."

I can't use **replace()** or **replaceFirst()**, it's a condition.

What is the best way to do this implementation?

Comment: why cant you use `replace`?

Comment: `replace` doesn't use regex.

Comment: `replace()` does not use Regex but `replaceAll()` does.

Comment: @MarioNavarroClaras how will you learn anything from this exercise if you let us do it? Seriously.

Comment: @MarioNavarroClaras please read this: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems?cb=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I can't use regex replace.* I don't know why you think that but you can simply do it by using `replace()`.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public String replace(String text) {
    String text = "My name is %NAME%.";
    String pattern = "%NAME%";
    String textReplaced = "Darius";

    String result = text.replace(pattern, textReplaced);
    System.out.println(result);
    return result;
}
```

Output:

```
My name is Darius.
```

Alternatively, if you do not want to use `replace()` then you can also do the following:

```
public String replace(String text) {
    String text = "My name is %NAME%.";
    String pattern = "%NAME%";
    String textReplaced = "Darius";

    String[] result = text.split(" ");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        sb.append(result[i].contains(pattern) ? textReplaced + " " : result[i] + " ");
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Don't you want to return `result`?

Comment: @Andy Sorry, my bad! :)

Comment: @MarioNavarroClaras Please check the updated solution.